# Sql string query not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, yii

I'm building some Sql queries in Yii framework.

So far all is working fine up until I need to compare a variable to a string.

Here is my function with the query:

```
public function countCanceled()
{
    $week      = Person_Event::model()->weekByDate();
    $week_id   = $week->id;
    $datalogin = mysqli_connect( /*connect is working fine*/);
    $sql       = "SELECT id FROM tbl_event WHERE week_id=$week_id AND status_id='canceled'";
    $query     = mysqli_query($datalogin, $sql);
    $numrows   = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    return $numrows;
}
```

Now , I clearly have one event with canceled status, and I ran the same query in MySql server and the result of 1 was given, so why in Yii it doesn't work?
(tried to switch "=" with "like" , made no difference)

p.s Yes , in this particular case I could use the built in Yii's queries , but I have other, much more complicated queries where I need to compare string.
Thanks,
Mark.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure this same query works in MySQL server? And why are you using simply mysqli_ not Yii adapter? Moreover you connect to database in method. Look how Yii adapter works. You can create quries by model in one line

Comment: week_id is working fine , the problem is in the canceled status. Edited my post about Yii's query tools

Comment: Show you data in table ..!!!

Comment: Uh, don't you need to parameterize the query? You have `$week_id` but then in the query it's hard-coded as 8.

Comment: I am , changed it into 8 just to simplify the example , though now I see that I did put the parameter code as well , so I changed it back to the original. In any way , the week is working fine. The problem is when I add the string comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is type of status_id if is char then data is space padded to full length. You can change it to varchar and then compare. And for like you can use LIKE 'canceled%'

ps. sorry I not have enough reputation to comment...:(

Best regards,
Nebojsa

Comment: It's case in the database and in the query same (Canceled vs canceled)? what you get when select status_id from table?

Comment: Th status is saved not in English , so no problems with case sensitivity. I gett 0 , though I have 1 event that was canceled for sure.

Comment: text comparation in mysql work correct and syntax from your query is ok. Try to copy text from table directly to php code and try again.

Comment: You mean even `$sql       = "SELECT id FROM tbl_event WHERE  status_id LIKE '%can%'";` does't work?

Comment: what you get when use $sql = "SELECT id FROM tbl_event WHERE week_id=$week_id"; ?

Comment: I get all the events that are on this week, no matte what their status is.